# Stop SharePoint behavior from jumping down to nearest input field in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint usually jumps into the closest input field when going into edit mode on a single page. Is there a way to turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the AllowFirstFocus-property to false on most FieldControls.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.basefieldcontrol.allowfirstfocus.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to set the it on the sitecolletion? I've tried to remove "HasInitialFocus" without any luck.

I've got a fixed menu / ribbon on the top of the page (masterpage) is there a way to ALWAYS set the focus on one of the field inside the fixed ribbon?

Comment: I would recommend using some kind of javascript which you call from your masterpage, to set focus to the desired field.

Comment: But would it not jump, even more with javascript?

Comment: I think if you use jquery and do something like: $(document).ready(function(){
$("#someid").focus();
});
I don't think the user will experience jumping..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by overriding one of SharePoints internal functions. It's a dirty hack though so be careful if you use it.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    RTE.PublishingRichTextEditor.setInitialFocusToEditableRegion = function(){};
}, 'SP.UI.RTE.Publishing.js');
```

This will effectively disable autofocus, but may have unintended side effects. Use with caution!

I only run the code if the page is in edit mode. The way I detect this is by using the code from here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12792/how-do-i-know-if-the-page-is-in-edit-mode-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent the autofocus with the following code

`This ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
            RTE.PublishingRichTextEditor.setInitialFocusToEditableRegion = function () { };
            RTE.Canvas.setInitialFocus = function () { };
        }, 'sp.ui.rte.publishing.js');`

Comment: Did you mean able instead of unable?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, I'm using SharePoint 2013 and Publishing Html Fields in page layouts.

Until I figured out a method in `sp.ui.rte.publishing.js` file and overwrite that method with nothing as below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.rte.publishing.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
   RTE.Canvas.initialFocusOnRichText = function () { };
});
```

I didn't find any console errors or any non desired behavior in Rich Html Field after overriding this function, but if someone notice please do comment.